# Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ALC05 (82LN005FCK) does not see a bootable USB drive with Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: boot, usb-installation

**Update**: Finally I have succeed to create a bootable USB drive using Rufus on Windows.

I have a new Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ALC05 (82LN005FCK), without OS. Using my old computer I have created a bootable USB startup disk with Kubuntu 22.10 (I have confirmed that the USB disk boots on my other (old) computer). But on this Lenovo it does not boot.

This Lenovo on startup only shows "Please select boot device" with option

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. NVMe: WDS ... (the SSD)
3. Setup.

There is no option for selecting USB. Nor booting from USB starts automatically.

In UEFI / BIOS (I am not sure, but inside it mentiones only BIOS) I have enabled USB booting, disabled Secure boot, and set the boot sequence to start with USB HDD. On the internet is a recommendation to disable "Fast Boot" but I haven't found it in the UEFI / BIOS.

The official Lenovo support informed me that this model "do not support Linux". But on the internet some dudes have Ubuntu running in it...

I have tried to change several settigns in UEFI / BIOS, used both USB-A ports but nothing helped.

An advice? Thanks!

Comment: It's UEFI like almost any PC since 2012.

Comment: FYI: If a thumb-drive boots on one device perfectly, that is no guarantee the thumb-drive is bootable on other devices with different hardware.  You can write an ISO many ways, so it's easier/bootable on some devices but alas won't boot on PCs of different types. Your logic on *boots on one device* only works if the devices have identical hardware plus details you've not specified. If I have issues booting an ISO in QA; I boot it on (1) identical hardware or almost identical, plus (2) two others very different before I decide the drive should boot ASSUMING ISO was written correctly/generically

Comment: Corrected the typo in the version. It is 22.10.

Thanks for the info about not universal bootability of medium! Maybe some suggestion about how to set ut the USB drive or the computer so I can install Kubuntu 22.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have succeed to create a bootable USB drive using Rufus on Windows.

I have also tried `dd` on Linux, but my machine run out of space, so I couldn't confirm the result.